# my enter key is not working for form?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I have a form which has one field `username`. If some one submit the `button "enter"` the next field `pop up`. I have  done using the `jquery` . And it after entering the `password` in that field when i click `the "login" button` (input type of button is submit in both case) request goes to the `server`. Every thing working fine for all browsers `except firefox`. When someone click the `login` button it works fine but when when i want to submit the form by `hitting the enter key` nothing happens. Each time for submit in `firefox` i have to use mouse. So, what can be the problem. I am not putting the code but it is simple `form.`

Comment: If you want an answer you'll have to provide some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for jQuery says:

> Depending on the browser, the Enter
>   key may only cause a form submission
>   if the form has exactly one text
>   field, or only when there is a submit
>   button present

If those conditions are not met, you may need to assign a key listener and listen for the enter key.  Also, I wouldn't be surprised if the "submit button" has to be an input of type submit, not a button... but I don't feel like testing it to confirm :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are your next buttons actually `<input type="submit">` buttons, or just regular `<button></button>` buttons?

As per [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196681/form-not-submitting-when-pressing-enter), the only way to process a form by pressing enter is to have 1) a sumbit button or 2) an onkeypress (or oninput) event in the input fields to listen for the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but the solution to your issue may be to set the focus on the button:

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').focus()
```

Hope this helps.